# Theorem still true if $X$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Consider the following theorem:

Let $S$ be a non-empty set and let $\{0\} \neq X$ be a vector space of bounded functions on $S$, with the condition that $S$ is a Banach space when $X$ is supplied with the supremum-norm. Suppose $f : S → \mathbb{F}$ is a function such that $fg \in X$ for all $g \in X$. Then the multiplication operator
$M_f : X → X$, defined by $M_f (g) = fg$ $(g ∈ X)$, is bounded.

I want to know,

- Is $f$ necessarily bounded?
- Is this theorem still true if $X$ is not complete.

Any insights are much appreciated.

Comment: If you plug in $g \equiv 1$, which is a bounded function, then you have $f = fg \in X$ so $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @mechanodroid What makes you think that $1\in X$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $1 \in \mathbb{F}$ for any field so the function $g : S \to \mathbb{F}$, $g(x) = 1, \forall x \in S$ is well-defined, and bounded. Hence $g \in X$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Is that supposed to be an answer to my question about what makes you think that $1\in X$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes.

Comment: @mechanodroid Then you failed. Read my answer to the question. As you can see, in that case $1\notin X$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could you please elaborate where exactly my argument fails?

Comment: @mechanodroid Which argument? Where exactly did you expose an argument which ends with “ … and therefore $1\in X$”?

Comment: My argument ends with $g$ is a bounded function from $S$ to $\mathbb{F}$. $X$ is the space of all bounded functions $S \to \mathbb{F}$ and therefore $g \in X$. I perhaps misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No. Otherwise the theorem would be trivial ($\|M_f\|\leqslant\sup|f|$).
- No. Take $S=[0,+\infty)$,$$X=\{g\colon S\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\,|\,g(x)=0\text{ if }x\gg0\},$$and $f(x)=x$. Then $g\in X\implies fg\in X$. However, $M_f$ is unbounded. Just take, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $g_n=\chi_{[0,n]}$. Then $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\|g_n\|_\infty=1$, but $\bigl\|M_f(g_n)\bigr\|=n$.

Comment: For the first part we would need a unbounded $f$ such that $M_f$ bounded, right?

Comment: @Fightclub1995 Right.

Comment: What is the meaning of $x\gg0$? How is $X$ the vector space of bounded functions on $S$? $X$ shoud be this:
$$X = \left\{g : [0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R} : |g| \le M \text{ for some } M > 0\right\}$$

Comment: @mechanodroid The meaning of “if $x\gg0$” is “if $x$ is large enough”. Please read again the original question: $X$ is **a** space of bounded functions, not **the** space of **all** bounded functions.